# intl-tel-input is not a function, помогите

Tags: javascript, html, css, form

Ребят, есть проблема. Вызываю плагин intl-tel-input. В ответ получаю: TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function. Я пытался всякими способами вызывать, а именно: (function($) {, jQuery(document).ready(function($) {, $(document).ready(function() {. Всёравно писало тоже самое. Подскажите как это решить, возникает проблема только с данным плагином. И можете на посоветовать другой хороший плагин такого же рода? Если кто не знает этот плагин добавляет коды стран к инпуту. Заранее всем спасибо!

```js
$("#phone-country").intlTelInput({
  utilsScript:'/path/to/utils.js',
  defaultCountry: 'auto',
  preferredCountries: ['ru']
});
```

Comment: я пологаю ты используешь либу для jQuery, но не подключаешь её. Тебе необходимо использовать `window.intTellInput()`. Ответ внизу написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

```
window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#phone-country"), {
  utilsScript:'/path/to/utils.js',
  defaultCountry: 'auto',
  preferredCountries: ['ru']
});
```